# IFS Formula in Excel: Formula will categorize positive numbers but not negative numbers

Tags: excel, ifs

I'm writing `IFS` Formula in Excel... I have positive and negative numbers that I'm grouping into categories. My formula works for positive numbers, but when it reads negative numbers, it results in a "0" answer. Question is - how can I get it to read negative numbers? In the example below, you see that positive numbers are categorized correctly, but negative numbers default to "0-80". Thank you!

Ex. Current Formula:

```
=IFS(EN:EN<-320,"-320+",EN:EN<-320,"-320--241",EN:EN<-240,"-160--240",EN:EN<-160,"-160--81",EN:EN<80,"0-80",EN:EN<160,"81-160",EN:EN<240,"161-240",EN:EN<320,"241-320",EN:EN<400,"321-400",EN:EN<480,"401-480",EN:EN<560,"481-560",EN:EN<640,"561-640",EN:EN>640,"640+")
```

*EN:EN is the column on my Excel sheet.

Output from Formula on my Excel sheet:

```
31.38   0-80

17.20   0-80

54.69   0-80

306.00  241-320

76.20   0-80

87.91   81-160

(112.00)    0-80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have two criterions the same:

```
    EN:EN<-320,"-320+",EN:EN<-320,"-320--241"
    ^^^^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

the second will never be found as the `IFS` stops at the first true.

2. You do not account for -80 to 0
3. Your conditions are off for the negative numbers:

```
=IFS(EN:EN<-320,"-320+",EN:EN<-240,"-320--241",EN:EN<-160,"-240--160",EN:EN<-80,"-160--81",EN:EN<0,"-80-0",EN:EN<80,"0-80",EN:EN<160,"81-160",EN:EN<240,"161-240",EN:EN<320,"241-320",EN:EN<400,"321-400",EN:EN<480,"401-480",EN:EN<560,"481-560",EN:EN<640,"561-640",EN:EN>640,"640+")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked. I really appreciate it! I hope many blessings come your way! You saved me a ton of time.

Comment: @Brandon please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.